# How to dynamically process text in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need a sugestion about dynamically processing and storing text depending on variables.

I've got a core text which is a content of my Swift-iOS application. But some part of this text change depend on user data, e.g.

```
"{{ if user.age > 15}} You are very young {{ else }} You are not too young {{ end }} but I will show you some magic in this app."
```

1. I have no idea how and where store such text in my app (store whole text in file, or split it and store separately),
2. How to process such text to display it depending on user variables.

Thank you for you sugestion.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to define a key for the texts (e.g.: `WelcomeTextUserYoung` and `WelcomeTextUserOld`), then associate those keys with the entire strings in the `.string` file. You'll have to write the logic (`user.age > 15`) in the class that shows the string (or in a common class if it's shown in more than one place).

I know that writing the whole string two times might sound as redundant and code repetition, but you never know if translating the text it remains separated as it is in english. So better implement good practices from the start, even if you don't think of localising the app ;)

Comment: What do you mean by ".string" file?

Comment: It's the file used for localisations, it just keeps a reference of strings related to keys. Then you get the string with the `NSLocalizedString` function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to store user data. Example:

```
var storage = NSUserDefaults.standartUserDefaults()
storage.setInteger(yourInt, forKey: "just a string using which you can access the value")
storage.setObject(yourObject, forKey: "the same as above") //yourObject can be a string, or a NSData
storage.synchronize()
```

To update UI elements you can use the timer connected to function, in which you get the object from NSUserDefaults and change the needed element (label, button, etc.)

Comment: Yeah I know, but this is not my question :)

Comment: @LakaLe_ so, please explain what do you need

Comment: as to storing the text - I suggest storing only the part you need to change, e.g. "You are very young"

Comment: I need a tip how to store and use a text content which some parts are depend of user data (doesn't matter where there are store)

Comment: @LakaLe_, you can store only changing part of you text or, e.g. the user's age, and in update function write a logic